# Notify when one search loop is complete

Tags: vimrc, search

I am searching a pattern with `/pattern` starting from a random line number `ln1`. Sometimes I kept on going with <kbd>n</kbd> without realizing that I completed searching the whole file.

Given the premise, I would like vim to print a message similar to something like `search 1 loop completed`, once I reach `ln1`.

> How can I edit my `.vimrc` to add this feature?

Comment: Isn't `'search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP'` enough for you ? Otherwise, you'll need to reprogram `n` to register the first use and detect when you cycle. Is it worth it?

Comment: @LucHermitte I think the second option is worth the keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have `s` in `:set shortmess?`. By default it shouldn't be there I think. If you happen to have it there, then add to `.vimrc`:

```
set shortmess-=s
```

Also see `:h 'shortmess'`

Comment: My `shortmess=filnxtToO`. I am a bit lost, does the exclusion of `s` in `shortmess` will let me print a message one I reached where I start?

Comment: This won't notify you when you reach the start, but the end of file - a cheap replacement that is already built into Vim. If you don't see that message and don't have `s` in `shortmess`, then you probably have a plugin or something mapped to `n` that overwrites default behaviour. Check what will be printed when you issue command `map n`? I have `vim-interestingwords` plugin that sets it's mapping on `n`, so I don't have `s` in `shortmess` variable and still no message displayed at the bottom of the file.

Comment: After `map n`, I get `No mapping found.` In my vim, there is a message printed similar to `search hit bottom` before search starts from the top, but I was specifically looking for a way to notify me when search reach its starting point.